# How do I use awk's single quotes within another single quote phrase?

Tags: awk, quoting, command

## Background

I am running a command that dispays processes on multiple hosts.  Below is the command:

`execAll -m "$HOSTS" 'hostname; ps -ef | grep build | grep -v grep; ipcs | grep 666'`

## Attempt

I want to now pipe the `ipcs | grep 666` portion of the command to `awk '{print $2}'` and then to `kill -9` to kill all the active processes.  Below is what I tried:

`execAll -m "$HOSTS" 'hostname; ps -ef | grep build | grep -v grep; ipcs | grep 666 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9'`

However, `awk` requires single quotes to run its argument, and the command above also requires single quotes.  The error I got was `Missing }.`, which I attribute to the quoting issue above.

## Question

How can I successfully run `awk` and kill the processes in the situation above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, `awk` requires single quotes to run its argument, [...]

Not really. The quotes are just a shell construct, they tell the shell not expand the dollar sign and to keep the string in one piece, instead of breaking it on the space. What awk sees is just the string `{print $2}`, it doesn't know how it's generated. You can achieve the same effect with double-quotes and backslash escapes. All of these should be the same:

```
awk '{print $2}'
awk "{print \$2}"
awk {print\ \$2}
```

The latter two fit inside the single-quoted string without issues.

Alternatively, if your shell is Bash or some other that supports ANSI C quoting, `$'..'`, you can change the outer quotes to `$'..'`, and then escape single-quotes with backslashes, too:

```
echo $'do or don\'t'
```

As the name implies, other C-style escapes (e.g. `\n`, `\t`, `\"`, `\'`, `\\`) work within `$'..'` too.

Answer (score 1):

Awk itself does not "require" single quotes. You just need to ensure the script body contains what you want it to contain. Double quotes are find if you escape the `$`:

```
execAll ... '...; ipcs | awk "/666/ {print \$2}" | xargs ...'
```